# How can I make Windows bootable again on OpenSuse Leap?

Tags: windows, grub2, opensuse, uefi

I have installed OpenSUSE Leap on an MS Windows (10 Home) laptop and it now only offers Linux in the boot menu. How can I get Windows into the boot menu?

Leap is currently 15.1¹, having been upgraded at least once, though I do not remember which versions I have had. I do not remember ever telling it not to support booting Windows.
The hardware is an Acer Aspire V Nitro laptop bought in Germany in 2015.

In `/boot/efi/EFI` I see only `bootx64.efi`, `fallback.efi` and `MokManager.efi`, while on my normal system (which can boot both Linux and Windows) `/boot/efi/EFI` has a subdirectory `Microsoft/Boot`.

I have these file systems:

- `/dev/sda1` (600 Mib) NTFS, “Basic data partition”, label `Recovery` *(not mounted in Linux)*
- `/dev/sda2` (300 Mib) FAT16 “EFI system partition”, mounted in Linux as `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/sda3` (128 MiB) “Microsoft reserved partition”, unknown file system, flags `msftres` *(not mounted in Linux)*
- `/dev/sda4` (190 GiB) NTFS “Basic data partition”, accessible in Linux as `/run/media/Acer`, flags `msftdata`, contains the Windows file system.

  - I have no reason to suppose these files are damaged; the file `osver.txt` says `10.0.17134`.
- `/dev/sda5` (12 MiB), Linux-swap, flags `swap`
- `/dev/sda6` (450 MiB), NTFS, flags `hidden, diag` *(not mounted in Linux)*
- `/dev/sda7` (16.28 GiB) NTFS “Basic data partition”, Label `Push Button Reset`, flags `hidden, diag` *(not mounted in Linux)*
- `/dev/sda8` (40 MiB), BTRFS “primary”, mounted in Linux as `/`
- `/dev/sda9` (671 GiB), XFS “primary”, mounted in Linux as `/home`

I notice that I have a `boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso` dated 2018-07-17 on my normal system.

¹ <sub>I do realise that it is time to upgrade to 15.2, but that is a separate issue! (I have already downloaded it.)</sub>

Comment: Is there any chance that Windows was installed using the legacy CSM boot instead of UEFI?

Comment: Also, you have a windows install on a 190MiB volume?  Are those units correct?

Comment: @jsbillings: (a) I am afraid I do not know how MS Windows was pre-installed on the laptop: can I see that in the files? (b) You are quite right, MSW is installed in a 190 **GiB** file system _(corrected, all partitions now listed as seen in `gparted`)_.

Comment: If you go into the BIOS and turn off UEFI (if that’s possible), does it boot windows?  The missing Microsoft directory might be because it was not installed as UEFI. However, if it was installed first, before Linux, it might have been installed with the right efi entries but the Linux install wrote a new vfat filesystem on top of the first partition.  Do you see any Microsoft entries in the output of “efibootmgr”?

Comment: @jsbillings: I may be a while in getting back to this, as we seldom want Windows on that system, but I shall check `efibootmgr` when I get the chance. MSW _was_ installed before Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue today since the last linux update (manjaro).
The bootmanager `grub` (2.04-21 on my machine) needed an additional configuration to detect windows and make it available in the boot menu.

Add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to `/etc/default/grub` and run `update-grub` or `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` not sure which one for suse.

However, I'd start investigating error messages from `update-grub` or `grub2-mkconfig` first, and then move on to partitions etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I need to read up a bit on `update-grub` / `grub2-mkconfig`, I think. I listed the partitions in case they suggested anything to anyone else. I may be a while in getting back to this, as we seldom need Windows on that system.

Comment: I was getting very frustrated with my SSD/NVME setup, and having very little luck. Finally, I went to the EFI partition on the windows drive (in Dolphin, no less), and copied the "Microsoft" folder to /boot/efi/EFI.

Ran os-prober again, and it found it! grub2-mkconfig added it to the menu, and it works great.